# Android adb shell ,ps-ef does not show any process?

Tags: android

i have many application running on my `emulator` but `ps -ef` does not show any `process` y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like Android's ps does not accept the argument -ef. Try issuing ps only?

Comment: @Dennis I think it's because there is no grep in the emulator. AFAIK, to get grep on Android devices, you have to root the device and then install busybox.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell ps | grep com.android.mms | awk '{print $2}'

This gives the process id of the attached process